# Force protobuf-net to serialize all default values

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a complex model serialized/deserialized with protobuf-net, and we had several bugs with this "feature" of not serializing default values.

Example:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo{
  public Foo(){
    // Value forced by constructor
    this.Value = 1;
  }

  // Buggy, when Value is set to zero
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
  public double Value {get; set}
}
```

When Value = 0, it is not serialized by protobuf-net, but during deserialization, the constructor forces Value to 1 (and protobuf-net do not change this).

In order to make it work, I need to force protobuf-net to serialize values, with:

```
  // Works fine
  [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
  public double Value {get; set}
```

But, as we already got bugs because of this feature, we'd like to force protobuf-net for the **whole model**, instead of marking every property.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this feature is fully supported. Actually, if I was forced to admit to bad design decisions in v1, the implicit-zero-defaults would be one of them - but for backwards compatibility the behaviour is retained by default. What you are looking for is `RuntimeTypeModel.UseImplicitZeroDefaults`, which is `true` by default.

To avoid changing the behaviour of code relying on v1 behaviour (via `Serilaizer.*`), you *cannot change* this feature on the *default* model, so what you need to do is:

1. define your own model/serializer-instance
2. set `UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false`, **before** using it
3. in your serialize/deserialize code, use this instance rather than `Serializer.*`

for example:

```
private static readonly RuntimeTypeModel serializer;
static MyType() { // your type-initializer for class MyType
    serializer = TypeModel.Create();
    serializer.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
}
... then when needed:
serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
...
ObjType obj = (ObjType)serializer.Deserialize(stream, null, typeof(ObjType));
```

Another approach I could perhaps consider in the future is allowing for assembly-level attributes; this would help in particular for anyone using "precompiler" (for example, targeting mobile devices or WinRT) - so (just thinking aloud):

```
// this feature ***does not currently exist***
[assembly:ProtoDefaults(UseImplicitZeroDefaults=false, SkipConstructor=true)]
```

which would then apply to all types *in that assembly*. Just a thought. Another obvious advantage is that it would work with code that uses the classic `Serializer.*` API.

Comment: I did not find TypeModel not RuntimeTypeModel in Protobuf-net v1 (found them in trunk). Is there a way to do this with protobuf v1?

Comment: @ghusse in v1? No. Is there a specific reason you want to avoid v2?

Comment: Migration of a component we are using in a stable product (and shipped).

Comment: Official protobuf wiki is still saying that v2 is in beta. Is it for real, or can we trust it?

Comment: @ghusse I updated that; yes, v2 is stable to the best of my knowledge and testing

Comment: Migration does not appear to be a piece of cake... It'll wait. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ghusse sure I can't help with anything?

Comment: @MarcGravell did anything change about this since 7 years? Like, maybe I can pass special flag to `ProtoContract` attribute to force-serialize all fields

Comment: @lolbas no; and with proto3 *further emphasizing* the zero/default duality, it isn't high on my list of things to do