# Protobuf-net 3: Boolean property showing wrong value after deserialization

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have created a class called User, which contain 2 property Name and IsSuperUser, IsSuperuser is by default true.I created an object of the same class and I've set the IsSuperUser = false.
after the deserialization the IsSuperUser value is true instead of false( Please see the output).

Please refer the my c# code below and check the proto_file generated after the serialization.

Using Protobuf-net 3.2.16 version.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkfvE.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zslY.jpg)

#protobuf-net #protobuf

The value cannot be change.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and data as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: But possibly related: [Force protobuf-net to serialize all default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12295976).

Comment: [Serialization of default values in optional members #363](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/363) might also apply.

Answer (score 1):

If the default isn't the usual defaults: *tell the serializer*; add `[DefaultValue(true)]` to the property.